# Exporting Javascript variable into React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, robotjs

I am trying to use Robot.js inside of a React.js application.  I have Robot.js installed and can run it to get the results in a separate file.  I cannot find a way to run Robot.js inside a React component because I get an error "robot.getMousePos()" is not a function.  All I really need is the value of "hex".  Is there a way to export the variable into my react component, Or even better run the Robot.js code in the same component without getting errors?

This is the Robot.js example:

```
const color = () => {
  // Get pixel color under the mouse.
  var robot = require("robotjs");

  // Get mouse position.
  var mouse = robot.getMousePos();

  // Get pixel color in hex format.
  var hex = robot.getPixelColor(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  console.log("#" + hex + " at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);
};

color();
```

it returns the value of "hex" which is equal to the hexidecimal color under the mouse at the given x and y coords (#1e1e1e at x:746 y:511)

I am trying to get that output into my React component whose code is here:

```
import React from "react";

const Robot = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Robot</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Robot;
```

Answer (score 2):

Robot.js is a library for desktop automation in Node.js.

React is a library for doing DOM processing in a browser.

You can't run code that depends on Node.js in a browser.

If you want these two bits of code to work together then you'll need to write a web service that they can communicate through (or run your code with something like Electron and then use the IPC API to communicate between the main and renderer processes).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you will have to run it with some buddy as Electron.
I paste below a briefing about how you could reach it with Electron from [here](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/using-robotjs-in-electron-app-190):

> I was having a similar issue.
>
> First I deleted entire node_modules directory and reinstalled them
> again by running npm installin project directory (you have to define
> all modules&versions in a package.json file for that).
>
> Then removed robotjs from node_modules directory manually. And then
> ran .\node_modules.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd.
>
> After that I installed robotjs again by npm install robotjs.
>
> Then cd .\node_modules\robotjs and node-gyp rebuild --runtime=electron
> --target=1.3.3 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --abi=48 (1.3.3 is current version of electron)
>
> and problem solved!

I had a similar issue, hopefully I was already using Electron and this worked fine.